# React Query devtools not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query, react-state-management, web-developer-toolbar

I am currently using react query in my project but the devtools Icon is not showing up anywhere on my screen. There are no errors in the console too. I am currently following a tutorial from youtube

Below is my package.json I have installed the latest versions too. But I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-query-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.0.10",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.0.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "serve-json": "json-server --watch db.json --port 4000"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom"
import "./App.css"
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools"
import { HomePage } from "./components/Home.page"
import { RQSuperHeroesPage } from "./components/RQSuperHeroes.page"
import { SuperHeroesPage } from "./components/SuperHeroes.page"

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/super-heroes">Traditional Super Heroes</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/rq-super-heroes">RQ Super Heroes</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/super-heroes">
              <SuperHeroesPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/rq-super-heroes">
              <RQSuperHeroesPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <HomePage />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: I have this problem in v4, It was displayed in the version 3.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this was an issue and fixed now on this beta version: https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/3916#issuecomment-1213172411

I did `yarn add @tanstack/react-query-devtools@4.0.11-beta.0` I know this is a beta version but now devtools shows up

Answer (score 1):

We're still trying to figure out a couple of bundling issues around the devtools and ESM support. Mainly, older bundlers like react-scripts v4 incorrectly pick up the wrong build. If you switch to react-scripts v5 (which came out more than 6 months ago) or something more modern like `vite`, things work fine. All our example use `vite` so you can see how we do it there.

We recently made a beta version that should address it, but it still has some issues and we're trying to figure it out here: https://github.com/TanStack/query/issues/3882

tl;dr: bundling is hard, sorry for the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different browser or check if it's updated. If you are using VSCode try restarting it.

Comment: Yep I have tried it on FireFox MSEdge and chorme but it does not seem to work. I started a new project on nextjs framework and the same setup worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue where I'm not able to view the dev tools console. Below is my package.json file. I'm not sure if it's something related to the webpack or rollup setup, but I couldn't find anything that looked like it would prevent it from displaying.

```
{
  "name": "mas-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@capacitor/app": "^4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.6.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/local-notifications": "^4.1.5",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@ionic-enterprise/identity-vault": "^5.9.6",
    "@ionic/react": "^6.5.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.8",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.24",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.23.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.0.11-beta.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "core-js": "^3.28.0",
    "ionicons": "^6.1.3",
    "luxon": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.1",
    "react-router": "^6.8.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.7.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.11",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^4.6.3",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "^15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/js": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/react": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/rollup": "^15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/webpack": "15.6.3",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.6.3",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-url": "^7.0.0",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^6.1.2",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.1",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "babel-jest": "28.1.1",
    "cypress": "^12.2.0",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.31.11",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.1",
    "nx": "15.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.10.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33940532)